# How can I mock server side requests in Playwright

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mocking, e2e-testing, playwright

I'm trying to find any docs or examples of how to mock server side requests with Playwright e2e testing. The official documentation on Playwright shares examples of how to mock/intercept client side calls. https://playwright.dev/docs/mock

Within a React app that is powered by Next.js for SSR, is there a way to mock API calls made before its returned to the client?

Comment: If you want to mock server-side requests that are directed to some third party API or even some other backend (micro-)service that is under your control, I posted an answer to the following question targeting this topic a few days ago => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72691792/mocking-back-end-3rd-party-calls-in-sveltekit-playwright/

Comment: In the example I gave in my answer in the link above, the backend is a Spring Boot (Java) application. That does not really matter though. I'm not a Next.js expert, but it should surely be possible to run your application with different configurations, such as test, dev or prod, in Next.js too. Dev would be targeting the test systems of third party API that you'd normally talk to instead of their production systems. In your `test` config, you would now target WireMock instead of any real system, as I've described in my answer mentioned above.